# Magento 2 :- Magento upgrade error 2.4.4 in php 8.1

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-upgrade, deprecated

When i run this command i got error

> php bin/magento maintenance:enable

PHP Deprecated:  Return type of phpseclib_mcrypt_filter::filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing) should either be compatible with php_user_filter::filter($in, $out, &$consumed, bool $closing): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **vendor/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat/lib/mcrypt.php** on line 1107

PHP Deprecated:  Return type of phpseclib_mcrypt_filter::onCreate() should either be compatible with php_user_filter::onCreate(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **vendor/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat/lib/mcrypt.php** on line 1158

Comment: Have you found any solution of this problem?

Comment: run `composer update`

Answer (score 1):

mcrypt module is depricated and seems to be enforced from php 8.1

Try below steps-

1. Check if mcrypt module is there using

   php -m
2. If mcrypt module is listed, disable it in php8.1
3. Restart php
4. Verify magento cmd now.

Comment: I don't have mcrypt module listed. What should I do then? And I am using docker container.

Answer (score 0):

First update the mcrypt module which is compatible with php 8.1

Check Here -
https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat