# Encountering a phpseclib_mcrypt_filter error while upgrading Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4.6

I'm in the process of upgrading Magento and encountering the following error. I'm unsure how to resolve it. Here's the error message.

> Deprecated: Return type of phpseclib_mcrypt_filter::filter($in, $out,
> &$consumed, $closing) should either be compatible with
> php_user_filter::filter($in, $out, &$consumed, bool $closing): int, or
> the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily
> suppress the notice in
> /home/mindtree/public_html/dev/vendor/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat/lib/mcrypt.php
> on line 1107

Answer (score 0):

`mcrypt` module is depricated from php 8.1

Check if mcrypt module is there

Run command from terminal : `php -m`

If `mcrypt` module is listed, disable it in php8.1

Restart php

Comment: I already checked it mcrypt is not there.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355979/magento-2-magento-upgrade-error-2-4-4-in-php-8-1

Comment: Verify once from phpinfo.php

Comment: I used the command php -m to list the modules, but I couldn't find mcrypt in the list.