# Getting mcrypt error while upgrading Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, magento2.4.6, mcrypt

While upgrading Magento 2 I'm getting the following error:

> Deprecated: Return type of phpseclib_mcrypt_filter::filter($in, $out,
> &$consumed, $closing) should either be compatible with
> php_user_filter::filter($in, $out, &$consumed, bool $closing): int, or
> the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily
> suppress the notice in
> /home/sampledata/public_html/dev/vendor/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat/lib/mcrypt.php
> on line 1107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. I installed the **sodium extension** in **PHP 8.1** after then restart **Apache** services and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

`mcrypt` module is deprecated from php 8.1

Check if the `mcrypt` module is there

Run command from terminal : `php -m`

If `mcrypt` module is listed, disable it in php8.1

**Restart php**

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355979/magento-2-magento-upgrade-error-2-4-4-in-php-8-1